# Is there any way to convert a tensorflow lite (.tflite) file back to a keras file (.h5)?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-lite

I had lost my dataset by a careless mistake. I have only my tflite file left in my hand. Is there any solution to reverse back h5 file. I have been done decent research in this but no solutions found.

Answer (score 11):

The conversion from a TensorFlow SaveModel or tf.keras H5 model to .tflite is an irreversible process. Specifically, the original model topology is optimized during the compilation by the TFLite converter, which leads to some loss of information. Also, the original tf.keras model's loss and optimizer configurations are discarded, because those aren't required for inference.

However, the .tflite file still contains some information that can help you restore the original trained model. Most importantly, the weight values are available, although they might be quantized, which could lead to some loss in precision.

The code example below shows you how to read weight values from a .tflite file after it's created from a simple trained `tf.keras.Model`.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# First, create and train a dummy model for demonstration purposes.
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=[5], activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")])
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="sgd")

xs = np.ones([8, 5])
ys = np.zeros([8, 1])
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=1)

# Convert it to a TFLite model file.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)

# Use `tf.lite.Interpreter` to load the written .tflite back from the file system.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="converted.tflite")
all_tensor_details = interpreter.get_tensor_details()
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

for tensor_item in all_tensor_details:
  print("Weight %s:" % tensor_item["name"])
  print(interpreter.tensor(tensor_item["index"])())
```

These weight values loaded back from the .tflite file can be used with `tf.keras.Model.set_weights()` method, which will allow you to re-inject the weight values into a new instance of trainable Model that you have in Python. Obviously, this requires you to still have access to the code that defines the model's architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know how to get the inputs of a particular node? In my task, I won't be able to create a keras model -- all what I have a tflite model, but I need to some reverse engineering and restore it for further keras training.

Comment: @pitfall In the meantime, did you find a solution to convert your tflite model back to Keras format?

Comment: Yes. Some colleague helped me to read the tflite attributes properly (via the .js API?). If you view the tflite model in netron, you actually can see all required layer parameters, e.g., number filters, dilation rate, padding, etc. and the node-to-node connections. That is said, you can recreate a keras model by 1) traversing the tflite computational graph to reconstruct the model architecture; and 2) load the tflite weights properly for each layer. Of course, you may still do some manual work if tf operators instead of layers are used in tflite.