# How to convert a .tflite file to a .h5 or .hdf5 file

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, hdf5, file-conversion, tensorflow-lite

Is it even possible to convert a .tflite to a .hdf5 file or .h5 file? As I searched google, all resources are about converting hf file to tflite file.

It's concerning a deep learning code. I have some trained and saved models as .hdf5 files. I have to convert them to tflite files to do some operation on those and then I need again those modified tflite files to be saved as .hdf5 files so that I can load the modified models for further operation. Is it doable? I have less understanding of tflite files and maybe I am missing any technicality.

Comment: You can't convert TFLite files back to H5 files. Considering retraining the model from an existing `.h5` file or loading the weights from it.

Comment: Refer to the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59566157/3903505