# Directly import tensorflow lite models into tensorflow/keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I am aware of converting tensorflow models to tflite, but is there a reverse procedure. I have been trying to dig the google documentation and this is not very clear to me.

I am trying to get this done for the models in here --> https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/tree/master/models/official/efficientnet/lite

Maybe I am missing something.  I am quite new to tensorflow.

Comment: why would you want to do the reverse procedure?

Comment: I would like to extract the weights in the tflite file to check the distribution of weights. Google has released some files for Efficientnet-lite and they have used different activation functions (like relu). I would like to restore the original models and make changes to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am asking the question similar to the following question which has been answered. Leaving this for anyone who searches with my keywords when beginning tensorflow:

[Is there any way to convert a tensorflow lite (.tflite) file back to a keras file (.h5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59559289/is-there-any-way-to-convert-a-tensorflow-lite-tflite-file-back-to-a-keras-fil)

Note that the answer above is valid for tensorflow 2.0