# Convert mediapipe iris tflite to tf/keras as a preprocessor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js, mediapipe

I'm trying to build an application that uses iris to estimate distance to the camera. I've found that Mediapipe have it (https://github.com/google/mediapipe/tree/master/mediapipe/modules/iris_landmark) but it is in tflite. I wish I could convert it to a tf/keras model as a preprocessor layer (non-trainable graph) (in Python/GoogleColab).
I've found many questions here in SO (like (1) ) that tries to convert it to h5/pb, which isn't exactly my case, since I don't need the optimizer, loss functions and so on. I just need to recover the layers and weights.

(1) [Is there any way to convert a tensorflow lite (.tflite) file back to a keras file (.h5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59559289/is-there-any-way-to-convert-a-tensorflow-lite-tflite-file-back-to-a-keras-fil)

(2) Mediapipe Iris is also in tfjs, which also doesnt solve my problem... https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/face-landmarks-detection ("shouldLoadIrisModel")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

converted to tfjs graph model a while back: https://github.com/vladmandic/human/tree/main/models

see same repository for my implementation

note that:

- `iris` model requires cropped face as input, so it needs to be paired with a face detector (any face detector will do, mediapipe uses `blazeface`)
- `iris` model doesn't really detect distance, it does precise iris box coordinates and given that biologically eye iris size is mostly fixed for all humans, simple math can then estimate the distance